# How do I create a reuseable AJAX call function and extract different values from the returned object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, asynchronous

I have a Nodejs application that displays randomly generated data on an html page.  There are 8 fields each populated from the values of an object with a page load.

I'd like to allow the user to change just a single field with the click of a button to generate a new random result in that field only.

I am using an AJAX calling function but having trouble making the function reusable for each field without rewriting mostly the exact same code 8 times.

I realize the final function will need some error handling as well.

```
function ajaxCall() {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var data;

  http.open("GET", "/randomStuff", true);
  http.onload = function() {

 // response is an object of 8 different properties
  data = JSON.parse(http.response);

 // this .log yields the object to the console without any errors
 // so I know it works and the correct data is there
  console.log(data);

 // This works of course but I want to simply call the function for each....
 // ... section and put a single value in each.
 // Without having to rewrite the entire ajaxCall function each time.
 insertP(data.propOne, 'sectionOneID')

 }
 http.send();
};

// This is the function that puts the data on the page.
function insertP(str, id) {
  var p = document.getElementById(id);
  p.textContent = str;
};
```

Using insertP or another as a callback seems to be the solution but I am not sure where to put it. In that case I could simply call the desired object property in the html.

Comment: `function ajaxCall(callback) {` - then use `callback(data.propOne, 'sectionOneID')` and call ajaxCall like `ajaxCall(insertP)` - though I may have misunderstood which part you want to parameterise

Comment: change function signature to `function ajaxCall(callback, p1, p2) {` ... change the call of `insertP` to `callback(data[p1], p2)` and execute ajaxCall like  `ajaxCall(insertP, "propOne", "sectionOneID")`

Comment: @JaromandaX  that's the stuff.  I tried something similar but used dot notation to pass the key and thought the problem was elsewhere.  Thanks for saving me from the rabbit hole.